# Qt5.7 on Ubuntu16.04 QT::serialport quick

Tags: c++, qt5.7

I have a project which I am building and developing at work on RedHat 7.2 using Qt5.6

At home I have Ubuntu16.04 running on VirtualBox, I've installed Qt5.7, when I try to build the same project I get 1 issue:

```
    Unknown module(s) in QT::serialport quick
```

In my 'pro' file I have:

```
    QT += core gui serialport quick xml
```

How do I add the serialport support, from what I've read it suggests it should already be present:

[Qt Serial Port](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Serial_Port#Qt5)

Thanks to @PeterT the serial port library problem has now been resolved, however 'quick' is still an issue, can anyone help with this?

Comment: if you're using the packages that come with ubuntu you need to install "libqt5serialport5-dev" .

Comment: Thank you, thats what I needed!

Comment: Any suggestions for 'quick' ?

Comment: Can anyone offer any help on this?